# A property question about WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textblock

Could any explain the following meaning of TextBlock.Text and Binding Path?

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Something" /> 
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This could also (and usually would) be rewritten as: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Something}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TextBlock..Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text.aspx)**: Property Gets or sets the text contents of a  TextBlock. This is a dependency property. Note that all non-text content is stripped out, resulting in a plain text representation of the  TextBlock contents. The default is  String.Empty.

**[Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)**: Gets or sets the path to the binding source property. The default is nullNothingnullptra null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).

[**DependencyProperty**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx): Represents a dependency property that is registered with the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) property system. Dependency properties provide support for value expressions, property invalidation and dependent-value coercion, default values, inheritance, data binding, animation, property change notification, and styling.

Comment: One more question: dependency property means?

Comment: What about the relationship between <Binding Path...> and <TextBlock.Text>? Does it mean Text has another propery named Binding Path?

Comment: It means that the Text property is bound to the value of "Something", which can be another property or resource.